# Drilling acrylic sheet to mount cabinet hinges

Tags: furniture

I am fitting small brass furniture hinges to 6mm thick Perspex acrylic sheet using 4mm dia setscrews, nuts & washers. Holes drilled 5mm using a wood drill bit. Nuts NOT over-tightened but Perspex has developed star cracks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're misusing the term "setscrews". Or maybe I misunderstand. At any rate, what constitutes overtightening is usually determined by the outcome. I'd say the outcome contradicts your claim.

Comment: Acrylic is a pain that way.  Try using polycarbonate.